# Why does the world exist, as opposed to nothingness, from Indian perspective?

Tags: universe, cosmology, nothing, nothingness

I came across this [Ted Talk](https://www.ted.com/speakers/jim_holt) by philosopher and author Jim Holt which raised the question as to why the universe, as we know it, exists at all as opposed to existence. The viewpoints discussed in the video are all modern and none of them speak in the context of Indian metaphysical treatises and philosophies like the Gita, Advaita, Dvaita, Buddhism etc. Just out of sheer curiosity, I wanted to know the standpoint of various Indian philosophies and treatises when it comes to the question "why does the world exist at all as opposed to nothingness".

Comment: heidegger said it was the fundmental question of metaphysics and a lot of buddhism is anti metaphysical.

Comment: The question is of Western origin, so Holt's omission is unsurprising. It goes back to Schelling's "why is there not nothing at all?”, Heidegger's version is more famous today. On [Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/44507) they suggest that Buddha was opposed to entertaining such questions, "*that is not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about it.*" But see [Rock, Why Does the Universe Exist? An Advaita Vedantic Perspective](https://digitalcommons.ciis.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1216&context=ijts-transpersonalstudies).

Comment: Shurangama sutra of Mahayana hinted on a colloquial level it's inconsistency falsehood explodes the world to exist: *this person contemplates the source of transformations. Seeing the movement and flow, he says there is change. Seeing the continuity, he says there is constancy. Where he can perceive something, he says there is production. Where he cannot perceive anything, he says there is destruction..He says that the arising of all things is existence and that the perishing of all things is nonexistence. The light of reason shows that his application of mind has led to inconsistent views...*

Comment: Would this be better asks on hinduism.SE or buddhism.SE?

Comment: Are you asking if existence is necessary? Is so, it is a fundamental question. I am not knowledgeable of any of the religious sources that you quote. There are philosophies which attempt to address this question. Panpsychism is an example.

Answer (score 4):

India has many religions and all of them have different theories. Hindus , Muslims , Christians , Sikhs , Jains , Parsis , Buddhists etc and even among them are difference of opinions.

It is nearly impossible for me at least ,to cover all the theories.
The most famous is that Brahma created the Universe and it is nourished by Vishnu and destroyed by Shiva.

Islam has other ideas. Allah created all.

Christians believe God created all.

I am not sure about others.

But Buddhists hold that no creator can be found but creation is there.

Answer (score 3):

OP: *"why does the world exist at all as opposed to nothingness?"*

One answer would be if the world was eternal : The world would exist because it had always existed.  However in the Pāli Canon, Gautama Buddha declares this undeclared, e.g. *Majjhima Nikaya* 63, [Cula-Malunkyovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.063.than.html):

> "So, Malunkyaputta, remember what is undeclared by me as undeclared,
> and what is declared by me as declared. And what is undeclared by me?
> 'The cosmos is eternal,' is undeclared by me. 'The cosmos is not
> eternal,' is undeclared by me. 'The cosmos is finite'... 'The cosmos
> is infinite,' ... is undeclared by me.

So the neat "eternal cosmos" solution is not available.  Nevertheless in the later [*Laṅkāvatāra Sūtra*](http://lirs.ru/do/lanka_eng/lanka-chapter-2.htm#XXXV) "beginningless time" is referred to, but is it rather metaphorical:

> Mahāmati, it is like the city of the Gandharvas which the unwitted
> take for a real city, though it is not so in fact.  This city appears
> in essence owing to their attachment to the memory of a city preserved
> in seed from beginningless time.  This city is thus neither existent
> nor non-existent. In the same way, Mahāmati, clinging to the memory
> (*vāsanā*) of erroneous speculations and doctrines since beginningless
> time, they hold fast to ideas such as oneness and otherness, being and
> non-being, and their thoughts are not at all clear about what is seen
> of Mind-only.

This leads somewhere interesting though.  Putting the question of the eternity of the cosmos aside in the manner of [Kant's unresolvable antimonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kant%27s_antinomies), or as a Derridean 'transcendental signified', in an interesting lecture by Zheng Li: [*What Is the Meaning of Beginningless?*](https://www.wholesomevision.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/20-English-The-Meaning-of-Beginningless-.pdf) eternity is found in the eighth consciousness tathāgatagarbha, (which seems to be potentiality).

> Because of the existence of the eighth consciousness tathāgatagarbha,
> the five aggregates and eighteen elements of all sentient beings, the
> twelve links of dependent arising, and all other dharmas can
> subsequently be produced and created. Based on the sequential arising
> and ordering of all these dharmas, the concept of "time" is then
> established. What is "time"? Time is a  construct based on the
> momentary change between consecutive moments in the mind of sentient
> beings.

Perhaps this is a modern interpretation of the [skandhas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skandha) (aggregates), but it has a passing similarity with the Kantian arisal of time as the motion or change of one thought to another.  The Kantian account of time—this is now *subjective* time; cosmic time being transcendentally inaccessible—is described in Jacques Derrida's *Heidegger: The Question of Being & History*, (pages 180-181).  This is how time is involved in the existence of the self: subjective, primordial time.

> To clarify what he calls Kant’s “obscure assertion” that “time affects
> a concept, in particular, the concept of the representations of
> objects” (*Kant and the Problem of Metaphysics*, 133), Heidegger shows
> what time as pure intuition must signify: originarily, it can in no
> way signify affection of something by something, affection of a being
> by another being, affection of an existing subject by something
> outside it: because time is nothing, as such it cannot affect
> anything. It is *affection of self by self*. Auto-affection, a concept
> that is as incomprehensible as is, in truth, the movement of
> temporalization. This auto-affection as temporality is not a
> characteristic affecting transcendental subjectivity, one of its
> attributes; it is, on the contrary, that starting from which the self,
> the *Selbst*, the I think constitutes itself and announces itself to
> itself. Heidegger writes, [French] p. 244:
>
> > As pure self-affection, time is not an acting affection that strikes a
> > self which is at hand (*vorhandenes Selbst*). Instead, as pure it
> > forms the essence (*Wesen*) of something like self-activating
> > (*Sich-selbst-angehen* as self-relating, to relate to self,
> > *angegangen werden zu können*). However, if it belongs to the essence of the finite subject to be able to be activated as a self,
> > then time
> > as pure self-affection forms the essential structure of subjectivity.
> > Only on the grounds of this self-hood can the finite creature be what
> > it must be: dependent upon taking things in stride (*angewiesen auf
> > Hinnahme*). ([*Kant and the Problem of Metaphysics*, 132](https://archive.org/details/kantproblemofmet00heid/page/194/mode/2up)) [GA 3, 1929]

So this now is subjective time originating with the self.  Inevitably this self exists if it is now reading, and would not be thinking anything if it did not exist.  Returning to the the question "why does the world exist at all as opposed to nothingness".  Why do I exist?  (Why does my world exist?)  Did it *always* exist in the potentiality of its eighth consciousness tathāgatagarbha?  On the possibility of ascertaining this I would return to [*The Kantbook*, p. 200](https://archive.org/details/kantproblemofmet00heid/page/200/mode/2up)

> It would be contrary to sense to try to effect an essential
> determination of primordial time itself with the aid of what is
> derived from it.

Again a closed avenue.  But returning to the question, now modified, why does one exist rather than not?  One can imagine a few of the myriad reasons and causes, (e.g. supernovae, parental romance etc.), and the astronomically minute probability of one's existence.  For a more traditional Indian perspective one direction of inquiry points to the eighth consciousness tathāgatagarbha.

Comment: I guess it is the Seventh Consciousness that all these questions arise from.

Comment: @ScottRowe Ha ha.  However, that one is 'deluded awareness' - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses)

Comment: Yes. As I understand it, either one is deluded and doesn't know it, or is deluded, but knows it. One can only strive to be less deluded, and still aware of fallibility. Sounds like... Science? From 2500 years ago?

Comment: @ScottRowe More like 1,700 years ago for the [*Yogācāra* system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses#Eightfold_network_of_primary_consciousnesses).  The ontology could be interesting but I'm not sold on the reincarnation angle.  "'After death a Tathagata exists' is undeclared."  [MN 63](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.063.than.html)